# How do I search for a model but only if it has at least one child association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models in my Ruby on Rails 5 (PostGres 9.5) application.  I have

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
```

and

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :machine
```

I want to search for Machine objects and so I have

```
  @results = Machine.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{machine_name}%")
                 .order("LOWER(name)")  
                 .paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

but the caveat is I only want to return objects that have at least one Part object associated with them.  I realize I coudl do

```
  @results = Machine.joins(:parts)
                 .where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{machine_name}%")
                 .order("LOWER(name)")  
                 .paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

but I see this as really inefficient is there are tens of thousands of associations.  What's the most efficient way to search for my Machine objects, but only if they have at least one Part association?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

After some searching this can be quite easily accomplished with

```
Machine.joins(:parts)
 .where('some condition')
 .group(:id)
 .having("count('parts.*') > 0")
```

Comment: If I have 1 million machines with parts, does this condiiton -- ".where(id: machine_ids)" cause PostGres to execute a "WHERE ID IN (id1, ... id1000000)" clause?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's not a super optimized version, it's just something that works fairly well in most situations.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Let me run some tests on my end to see how quickly things shake out.

Comment: There is also one other way, and that is to use counter caching. http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/

Comment: @Dave I edited the answer with a much better and faster solution, hope it works.